# Smartphone data usage when travelling in US

Tags: technology, phone, travel

I'm planning a trip to the US in an area I don't know well. It would be really helpful if I have my smartphone with me for things like google maps and staying in touch with people. Sadly, my provider doesn't have a good plan for travel, the most [they have is](https://www.koodomobile.com/add-ons) for $30 of which for 3 days you get 150MB of data plus free calls and texts. 150MB is hardly anything.

Also, I have 'Shaw Open' but that doesn't work in the US. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to try asking on our [Travel site](http://travel.stackexchange.com). This is a big topic over there.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find it easier and less expensive to purchase a local prepaid phone for traveling to the US from overseas. Many include "unlimited" data plans. And if you are going to be in the US for more than a few days, it can save you a great deal of money.

It appears that you have several choices for smartphones from the local retailers (Walmart, among so many others). As of this writing, the prices run about $100, including the phone and air time.

You can forward calls from your normal phone to the prepaid, but may incur charges from your home cell phone carrier. Check with them.

Comment: Good answer! Also, my upvote on your answer pushed you past 3000 reputation points, so congratulations. :)

Comment: How/where is this done? Can I just by the sim card as I already have the phone?

Comment: If your phone uses the same frequencies as are used in the US, I suppose it is possible to get a SIM card. Some of the companies in the US will not allow phones on their network that aren't branded to the company, which is why I suggested the prepaid phone from a local provider.